# React Router Link callback function

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am using **react-router-dom v4** and I want to execute a callback function after I click on link navigation / the route has changed.

```
<nav>
  <ul>
    {this.routes.map((route) => <li key={route.id}><Link to={route.path} >{route.title}</Link></li>)}
  </ul>
</nav>

<main>
  {this.routes.map((route) => 
    <Route 
      key={route.id}
      path={route.path}
      onEnter={() = > console.log('callback after route change')}
      exact
      component={route.component} />
   )}
</main>
```

I tried **onEnter** on **Route** but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

onEnter is removed in react-router v4, it is available in react-router v3.

You can give a try to use componentWillMount function of the component to which you are navigating.

Hope this will help you out.

Comment: thanks for the reply, but that solution will imply to write that componentWillMount function for every component

Comment: you can create a hoc which will call on every route and inside hoc you can add your algorithm in that way you can avoid writing the same code multiple times

Comment: `componentWillMount` is deprecated https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#unsafe_componentwillmount